# How can I set a transparent background in a GTK# TextView using Mono?

Tags: c#, mono, textview, transparency, gtk#

I have a Gtk.Window with a background image.  It is filled with TextViews mostly in Paned widgets.  I want the TextViews to have a transparent background.  Ideally, black with half alpha, but I can live with a fully transparent background.  Does anyone know if this is possible?  Is there maybe a way to override some kind of DrawBackground in a custom TextView subclass?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use C# just simple gtk with c++. This should help

```
view=gtk_text_view_new ();
gtk_widget_set_opacity (view,0.2);
```